# Import the csv data to database and update the existing data using their id in django

Tags: python, django

I want to update some existing data by uploading the CSV file.

I have some data in the MySQL database and some of them have spelling mistakes and some others mistakes.

So I have correct data on the CSV file and I want to upload it and update existing data on the database. It will take an `id` and update the existing data.

Below code for importing data into the database. So how can I modify this code to update the existing data of the database?

views.py

```
# Import the data to database
def import_countries(request):
    with open('C:/python/Azuro/azuro_django/pms/templates/pms/countryname.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = Country(currency=row['Currency'], name=row['Country'])
            data.save()
            
    return HttpResponse('Data Uploaded!!')
```

**Update:**

Is there any way to perform this task without `bulk_update`.

I want to read a CSV file then check if the CSV file's data is present in the database or not. - if 'Yes' then just start an iteration to update the existing data into the database by its id. - if 'Not' then print a list that contains data(id) that is present in the database and print another list that contains the data(id) which is not present in the database

Thanks!

Comment: does your csv row contain id?

Comment: Yes, using that `id` I want to update existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could update a record in django, one of which is [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), also, you can get the record and set the necessary fields you want to update.  The problem with those approach is that it will do a query into the database for each record, and the latter will do two queries in each record (one for get and one for update).

In your case, that is not good as you will need to update several records.  What you can do is use [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) to update several records in one query:

```
countries_to_update = []
for row in reader:
    countries_to_update.append(
        Country(id=row["id"], currency=row["Currency"], name=row["Country"])
    )

Country.objects.bulk_update(countries_to_update, fields=["currency", "name"])
```

Take note that it will only update the fields you specified in the `"fields"` argument, in the case above, only `"currency"` and `"name"` will be updated.

Comment: Is there is any way to perform this task without using `bulk_update`?

Comment: Example: I want to read a CSV file then check if the CSV file's data is present in the database or not.
- if 'Yes' then just start an iteration to update the existing data into the database by its `id`.
- if 'Not' then print a list that contains data(id) that is present in the database and print another list that contains the data(id) which is not present in the database.

Comment: you should be able to query record per iteration. if Country.objects.filter(id=row["id"]).exists(), or you can get the record with try/except